# React, cart with context and localstorage

Tags: reactjs

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-cart-context-delete-total-putwb1?file=Cart.tsx)

It's a cart with products that can be added to a cart and show a total.

I'm using context for the state as the products and cart are different components.

I'd like to use localstorage to storage the cart and total data so if the page is refreshed the cart data won't be lost.

I can store the data in the localstorage with

```
useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(items));
    total();
  }, [items]);
```

but I'm not sure how to use this when the page loads again.

I want a cart where I can add and delete products and have them stored in local storage, I'm not sure if using context is the best option or it might be better just using localstorge.

But anyway how can I use localstorage to load the cart and total data when the page is refreshed.

Comment: I've updated my answer, with demo link

Comment: You'll have to be super careful with saving those stuff in local storage to invalidate them when the user signs out. Sometimes saving in the backend is the right way, especially if you want cross-browser synchronization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made few changes [click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-cart-context-delete-total-mwjkip?file=context.tsx)

You can simply add the below code in your `carts.tsx` file

```
const [isInitiallyFetched, setIsInitiallyFetched] = useState(false);    
const addItems = useContext(AddCartContext);

useEffect(()=>{
  let prev_items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || [];
  addItems(prev_items)
  setIsInitiallyFetched(true)
},[])

useEffect(() => {
  if(isInitiallyFetched){
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(items));
    total();
  }
}, [items]);
```

make sure to import `AddCartContext`.

And in `context.tsx`

```
   <AddCartContext.Provider
      value={useCallback(item => {
        if (Array.isArray(item)) {
          setItems([...itemsRef.current, ...item]);
        } else {
          setItems([...itemsRef.current, item]);
        }
      }, [])}
    >
```

Now try refreshing the page, Your previous cart state will be restored.
Happy Coding...

Answer (score 3):

Hi you can get `localStorage` data in the `useEffect` like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(!items.length){
    const jsonItems = localStorage.getItem("cart");
    const localItems = JSON.parse(jsonItems);
    setItems(jsonItems)
  }
}, [items]);
```

And in case you want to read data from `localStorage` just the first time component renders you can do something like this:

```
const [avoidReading, setAvoidReading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!items.length && !avoidReading) {
    const jsonItems = localStorage.getItem("cart");
    const localItems = JSON.parse(jsonItems);
    setItems(jsonItems);
  }
}, [items, avoidReading]);
```

but if you sure you want to use `localStorage` a better and cleaner way is to use `useLocalStorage` custom `hook` which is like `useState` but it can persist data through `localStorage`, read more about it here: https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/

all you need to do is replace `useState` in your `Provider` to `useLocalStorage` and you're good to go.

Comment: Taghi, your first answer uses `setItems` but I don't have a setItems, is this something I should add - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-cart-context-delete-total-kdx4ju?file=Cart.tsx

Comment: @lomine yes, you need an state for `items`

Comment: @TaghiKhavari How do I get a value from localStorage using useLocalStorage Hook ?

Answer (score 0):

```
const cartfromlocalstorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || '[]'

 useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart))
  }, [cart]);
```